# Getting all values from UL tags in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have the below HTML code. I want to get all the text within the hyperlink tag.

```
<div ng-model='sCur'>
   <ul sa-toggle-menu="" role="menu" class="sa-dropdown-menu">
      <li><a ng-bind="item[lebel]" ng-click="itemSelect(item)" class="ng-binding">1</a>
      <li><a ng-bind="item[lebel]" ng-click="itemSelect(item)" class="ng-binding">2</a>
      <li><a ng-bind="item[lebel]" ng-click="itemSelect(item)" class="ng-binding">3</a> 
   </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying the below java code. But I get empty text values.

```
List<WebElement> currencies = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[ng-model='sCur'] ul li"));

for (WebElement option : currencies) {
    System.out.println("Text :" + option.getText());
}
```

Comment: may be you should add ... ul li a? Otherwise the get text will try to get the text from li not a

Comment: It didn't work. I already tried the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. Here was the issue.

As the data is bound to the element on runtime, the list was not present in the DOM. Only when the drop down arrow is clicked, the elements are added to the DOM.

After triggering the combobox click, all the elements became valid and getText() worked.

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[ng-model='sCur'] ul")).click();

List<WebElement> currencies = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[ng-model='sCur'] ul li a"));

for (WebElement option : currencies) {
    System.out.println("Text :" + option.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are selecting `li` elements and not `a` elements. Use

```
By.cssSelector("div[ng-model='sCur'] ul li a")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
List<WebElement> currencies = driver.findElements(By.className("ng-binding"));  
for (WebElement option : currencies) {
  System.out.println("Text :" + option.getAttribute("ng-bind"));
  System.out.println("Text :" + option.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.naukri.com/");
// Click on dropdown
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='exp_dd']/div[1]/span")).click();
//Capture all dropdown element in a List
java.util.List<WebElement> elements =driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='exp_dd']/div[2]//ul/li"));

for(WebElement ele:elements){
    String str=ele.getText();
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("8"))
        ele.click();
}
```